# Rebuilding a Newer Version of a Deb Package

Tags: package-management, ppa, apt, deb, versions

What's the best way to update (through rebuild from source) a Debian/Ubuntu-package to a more recent version? Should I be using `apt source` in all cases including when I want to publish it as Personal Package Archive? I would like to have Intel TBB 4.0 instead of 3.0, which is pre-packaged in Ubuntu 11.10. So how do I use an existing `apt source` tar-ball and modify it to support the new version? Is there some nice tutorial listing what Debian package specific files I should modify?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the best way, but i would do it by the easiest way. I think that the backporting is a bit easier than to build from the scratch.

The Precise (planned release April 26th 2012) repositories do have the tbb 4.0+r233: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tbb&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all

The Debian has : http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=tbb&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: How do I backport Precise TBB 4.0 to Oneiric then?